# ScrollView with an OnClickListeners for each item?

Tags: android

I have made a ScrollView and filled it with ImageViews that have OnClickListeners attached to them, but now when I try to scroll the ScrollView, it seems that the OnClickListeners get in the way and don't give a smooth scroll.

Is there a way to fix that, other then using a ListView instead of ScrollView?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to have an OnClickListener for each ImageView.

The callback definition is

```
public abstract void onClick (View v)
```

where `v` is the view that was clicked.

Depending on what you want to do, you can identify the specific view or not. IF you just want to do something generic, (for example, applying a tint), then this is very straightforward

```
...
public void onClick(View v) {
    ImageView iv = (ImageView) v;
    iv.setTint(Color.BLUE); // Or whatever generic operation you want
}
```

If you need to identify the view specifically, e.g. it's part of an XML menu, then I usually use the itemID to identify it

```
...
public void onClick(View v) {
    int id = v.getId();
    switch (id) {
        case R.id.save:
          //do stuff
          break;
        case R.id.open:
           //do stuff
           break;
    }
}
```

If the views aren't static, then you can use the `setTag()` and `getTag()` methods to uniquely identify (and associate useful data!) with each view:

```
...
public void onClick(View v) {
    // the MyViewInfo object was associated with the view somewhere else, presumably when the view was created
    MyViewInfo info = (MyViewInfo) v.getTag();
    File datafile = info.getFileName();
    ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Just one more thing, since it's all dynamic, how should I associate this onClick function with my ImageView that has a tag set to it?

Comment: Your class,X, that holds the `onClick` method must implement the `View.onClickListener` interface. You then need to call setOnClickListener(x) for each view, where x is an instance of X. If the container view is smart enough to propogate click events to all its child views, then you might only have to call `setOnClickListener` on the parent view.